# SwiftUI - Label not aligning to left

Tags: swiftui, label, vstack

I've got a very basic view with a label in it in SwiftUI and I'm struggling to get it to align to the left. This is what it is:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
  Label("Hi", ...)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

No matter what I've tried the label stays in the center of the view. How can I fix this?

Comment: It is most likely one of the parent views that you haven't shown. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `alignment` parameter in the `VStack` initialiser determines that its child views will align to the stack's leading edge.

What you are missing is an `alignment` parameter in the `frame` modifier that tells the layout system how the content should position itself within your expanded frame.

```swift
VStack(alignment :.leading) { // alignment of the two labels
  Label("Hi", ...)
  Label("Second line", ...)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // alignment of the whole stack in the larger frame
```